# onChanged method with setState of TextField does not update the result?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am experimenting with flutter and I have a very simple code as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  static double d = 0;
  static TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    editingController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    editingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Calc calc = Calc(d: d, e: editingController);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                      d = double.parse(value);
                    } else if (value.isEmpty) {
                      d = 0;
                    }
                  });
                },
                inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                    RegExp(r'(^(\d{1,})\.?(\d{0,2}))'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                controller: editingController,
                inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                    RegExp(r'(^(\d{1,})\.?(\d{0,2}))'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Text(
                'First Text Field Value + 2 = \n${calc.dString()}',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.purpleAccent),
              ),
              Text(
                calc.eString(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Calc {
  final double d;
  final TextEditingController e;

  Calc({this.d, this.e});

  String dString() {
    double result = d + 2;
    return result.toStringAsFixed(0);
  }

  String eString() {
    return e.text;
  }
}
```

As we can see I am passing both the text fields' values into another class for some math and getting the results. These results are displayed using the Text widgets.

For the **1st TextField**, I have used **onChange** method, and for the **2nd TextField**, I have used TextEditingController.
I get return value for 2nd TextField from the **Calc class**, but not for the 1st TextField!
I think I am missing something basic and I did not find any solution so far. Can you please help me what am I missing here.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st of all, you are creating just a single object of `Calc`,

yes as you can see your 2nd textField update perfectly because it's using `TextEditingController` but for the 1st one, it just call once and become `2` because of `dString()`, while on 1st run `d` becomes `0` passed on `Calc`.

if you want to use `Calc` to update text, you can simply put it inside `build` method like this , i dont suggest it, you can use callBackMethod to handle this or use another `TextEditingController`.
Hope you get it now

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Calc calc = Calc(d: d, e: editingController);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Calc Object is not being affect by setState() call. To run be able to get value of the `calc`object, run it in you `onChanged()` function.